# Execute history or fc from script or non-interactive zsh instance

Tags: scripting, zsh, command-history

From reading the zsh docs, `history` and `fc` won't access the full `~/.zsh_history` in non-interactive mode.  I'm looking for a way to make this happen so I can script a search utility.  Things I've tried:

```bsh
➜  ~ fc -l 0 1
    1  ls
➜  ~ echo $HISTFILE
/Users/username/.zsh_history
➜  ~ zsh -c 'echo $HISTFILE'

➜  ~ zsh -c 'HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history; echo $HISTFILE'
/Users/username/.zsh_history
➜  ~ zsh -c 'HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history; history'
zsh:fc:1: no such event: 1
➜  ~ zsh -c 'HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history; fc -l 0 1'
zsh:fc:1: no events in that range
➜  ~ zsh -c 'HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history; fc -R; fc -l 0 1'
zsh:fc:1: no events in that range
➜  ~ zsh -c 'HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history; fc -R -l 0 1'
<NO OUTPUT>
```

In bash, there's a history option you can enable with `set -o history` but that doesn't exist for zsh.

The alternative approach is to access `~/.zsh_history` file directly but then I'd lose out on the formatting support that `history` and `fc` do.  Is there a built-in utility I could pipe `~/.zsh_history` to do said formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `fc -R` to read a history file. This only reads the last `$HISTSIZE` entries, so set `HISTSIZE` to a large value before calling `fc`.

```
HISTSIZE=999999999
fc -R ~/.zsh_history
```

Comment: Writes to history ``print -s`` or ``fc -W`` and ``fc -A`` don't seem to work from non-interactive zsh shell. Is there a way around? I cannot force an interactive shell, and intend to use immediately written history in next call to vared.